# Removed linkCreation.dotm keeps coming back (MS Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, plugins

As discussed here on the Microsoft Forum - it;s not hard to solve the linkCreation plugin issue. However, it seems that every time I remove it, another one is created so when I open Word again after a while, it's there again and giving me startup problems. Anyone who knows how to permanently remove linkCreation.dotm?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0a463ed-97a3-4f93-90fe-5071be819ce6/compile-error-in-hidden-modulelink-on-mac-365

As suggested in most answers in this thread, I found the Startup/Word folder and removed the file. However, as said, after a while the linkCreation.dotm is back and causes issues on startup. I want to find out if others have the same problem.

~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Startup/Word/

Comment: The link shows different solutions. Please [edit] your question and describe what you did exactly, what were the expected results and what happened instead.

Comment: ok done........

Answer (score -1):

I tried Uninstalling and Re-installing Acrobat DC from Creative Cloud, but this didn't fix the issue for me.

Deleting "linkCreation.dotm" from the following folders:

```
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Startup/Word/
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Startup/PowerPoint/
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Startup/Excel/
```

... helped ... for a little while. Then the file reappeared.

Doing a hard drive search, i found the linkCreation.dotm at this location too.

```
  /Library/Application Support/Adobe/MACPDFM/DC/linkCreation.dotm
```

I ended up deleting the following directory:

```
  /Library/Application Support/Adobe/MACPDFM
```

as well as the linkCreation.dotm file from the earlier locations too.

And so far, so good.

I noticed a day or so later (after a reboot) that a new "MACPDFM" directory appeared, but without the linkCreation.dotm file. No recurrence of the issue yet.

Hope this helps someone.

---

**UPDATE 14 DEC 2019:** Looks like the file paths may have changed in a recent update -- also check for "linkCreation.dotm" in these directories:

```
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Word/
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/PowerPoint/
  ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/Startup.localized/Excel/
```

---

**UPDATE 3 AUG 2021:** Acrobat is back causing problems for me again, so am now using this command to purge the files causing it for me:

```
sudo find \
    ~/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office \
    /Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/MACPDFM \
    -name "linkCreation.dotm" \
    -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Command will display path to the files it finds, and prompt you to confirm to delete.